# jQuery Mobile panel won't hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I'm trying to add a jQuery mobile slide panel. I can get the slider to pop out which is triggered by an anchor link but it won't hide again. Do I need to add an addition jquery script?

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
    <h1>This panel won't disappear</h1>
</div><!-- /panel -->
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="temp-speech"><a href="#mypanel"><img src="images/speech_bub.png" /></a></div>
</div>

</div><!-- page -->
</body>
```

I've created an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AZLWd/

Comment: Page div should be inside body tag. Your html syntax isn't correct. Add `data-rel="panel"` to anchor which opens the panel.

Comment: @Omar thanks, it still doesn't close though. I changed the anchor to `<a href="#mypanel" data-rel="panel">` is that correct?

Comment: Is page div inside body tag?

Comment: Yes it's inside the body.

Comment: Is the panel placed under page div directly? Are you using `data-dismissible="false"` on the panel? Pls add more details.

Comment: I'm not using `data-dismissible="false"` This is a temp page I'm testing on, all it has in the html is what's posted above besides your two suggested changes.

Comment: Then if you click outside the panel it should close by itself.

Comment: it still doesn't close :/

Comment: @Omar I added a jsfiddle above

Comment: You should wrap page contents in `<div class ="ui-content" role="main">` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AZLWd/2/

Comment: ahhh legend, thank you :) Do you want to post it as an answer so I can give you the accolades?

Comment: I'll post a comprehensive answer later. Im using mobile now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon opening a *panel*, checks for `.ui-header` (internal), `.ui-content` and `.ui-footer` (internal) to wrap them in `.ui-panel-wrappr` div. That div (`.ui-panel-wrapper`) receives *open* and *close* animation classes. If *panel* fails to find any of the aforementioned div's, the *close* animation classes won't be added and *panel* remains open.

[Panel widget](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/panel.js#L107):

```
_getWrapper: function () {
     var wrapper = this._page().find("." + this.options.classes.pageWrapper);
     if (wrapper.length === 0) {
         wrapper = this._page().children(".ui-header:not(.ui-header-fixed), .ui-content:not(.ui-popup), .ui-footer:not(.ui-footer-fixed)")
             .wrapAll("<div class='" + this.options.classes.pageWrapper + "'></div>")
             .parent();
     }
     return wrapper;
 },
```

In light of the above, any page should contain *at least* a header, footer or a content div in order to function as it should.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="panel">
    <!-- panel content -->
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <!-- contents -->
  </div>
</div>
```